# PHP Regex Strip Away All Emojis

Tags: php, regex, emoji

I am trying to strip away all non-allowed characters from a string using regex. Here is my current php code

```
$input = "";

$pattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9_ !@#$%^&*();\\\/|<>\"'+\-.,:?=]";
$message = preg_replace($pattern,"",$input);

if (empty($message)) {
    echo "The string is empty";
}
else {
    echo $message;
}
```

The emoji gets printed out when I run this when I want it to print out "The string is empty.".

When I put my regex code into http://regexr.com/ it shows that the emoji is not matching, but when I run the code it gets printed out. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your pattern is incorrect. If you want to strip away all the characters that are *not* in the list provided, then you have to use a negating character class: `[^...]`. Also, currently, `[` and `]` are being used as delimiters, which means, the pattern isn't seen as a character class.

The pattern should be:

```
$pattern = "~[^a-zA-Z0-9_ !@#$%^&*();\\\/|<>\"'+.,:?=-]~";
```

This should now strip away the emoji and print your message.

Comment: `$pattern = "~[^!-~]~`"; it's simpler and serve the same purpose. We can use ranges different than the usual `a-z` and `0-9` in regular expressions.

Comment: @yeyo: What if the OP wanted to remove strings that are not alphabets, number or the characters in the set? Note that you shouldn't really use `-` in the middle of a character class. Your regex should be `[^!~-]` or `[^-!~]`.

Comment: No, sorry you are misinterpreting my comment, the `-` goes in the middle. `[^!-~]` matches any single character that is not part of the ASCII range `!` to `~`. In other words `[^!-~]` is equals to the expression `[^a-zA-Z0-9_ !@#$%^&*();\\\/|<>\"'+.,:?=-]`. Try it :)

Comment: those solutions stripe away the accents (ie: `é`), this si problematic for many non English languages

Comment: @Bruno I agree. You should be able to find better solutions for matching emojis though.

Comment: I just posted a response below on how we did it

Answer (score 8):

This pattern should do the trick :

`$filteredString = preg_replace('/([^-\p{L}\x00-\x7F]+)/u', '', $rawString);`

Some sequences are quite rare, so let's explain them:

- `\p{L}` matches any kind of letter from any language
- `\x00-\x7F` a single character in the range between  (index 0) and  (index 127) (case sensitive)
- the `u` modifier who turns on additional functionality of PCRE that is incompatible with Perl. Pattern and subject strings are treated as UTF-8.